# true or false statements based on predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Q) Let $P(x,y)$ be the predicate $y=2x$. Consider the statements

a)$\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$

b)$\forall y \exists x P(x,y)$

c)$\exists y \forall x P(x,y)$

where $x$ and $y$ range over the integers. Write whether each statement is true or false and give a very short explanation of why

For a) it is false, since for all the values of $x$ won't give the same value of a particular $y$.

For b) it is false, since all the values of $y$ cannot be formed by any particular $x$. In the case of $y=1$ it requires $x=0.5$, which is not a discrete number.

c) false, some values of $y$ cannot be obtained by all the values of $x$. It would require a $x=y/2$ value.

Are my answers correct? Does the justification make sense? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The assertion a) is true.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x, y)$ is the statement $y = 2x$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Thus, the statement $\forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ means that for each integer $x$, there exists an integer $y$ such that $y = 2x$.  Since the integers are closed under multiplication, this statement is true.

The statement $\forall y \exists x P(x, y)$ asserts that every integer is even.  You correctly supplied a counterexample to this statement by choosing $y = 1$.

The statement $\exists y \forall x P(x, y)$ asserts that there exists a particular integer $y$ that is the double of every integer $x$.  The statement is false since the function $y = 2x$ is strictly increasing.  If $x_1 < x_2$, then $y_1 = 2x_1 < 2x_2 = y_2$.  In particular, there does not exist an integer $y$ such that $y = 2 \cdot 0 = 0$ and $y = 2 \cdot 1 = 2$.